# parcel-plugin-transcrypt fails with 'Error: Cannot find module 'parcel-bundler/src/Logger'

Tags: javascript, python, parceljs, transcrypt

In a web project using `yarn` as package manager and `parcel` as bundler, I want to let Parcel transpile Transcrypt (Python) files to Javascript.

For this I installed `parcel-plugin-transcrypt`. But now when I bundle the project via `parcel serve` I get the following error:

> Cannot find module 'parcel-bundler/src/Logger

Googling shows that this seems to be some version issue other plugins have [encountered](https://github.com/albinotonnina/parcel-plugin-wrapper/issues/3) [too](https://github.com/BoltDoggy/parcel-plugin-eslint/issues/16). However I could not find a solution for `parcel-plugin-transcrypt`.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin for Transcrypt references files that have been refactored in newer versions of the bundler.  To get it to work you need to add three missing files required by the build process. It's a work around for an underlying issue, but it fixes the problem for now. I use 3 wget commands to pull the files out of github and put them into the appropriate node_modules folder. So after installing parcel-bundler with npm, from the root folder of the project I run these:

```
wget -P ./node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/b1e6d59cc44489f20013fa3171e09788978d7aed/packages/core/parcel-bundler/src/Logger.js

wget -P ./node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/utils/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/b1e6d59cc44489f20013fa3171e09788978d7aed/packages/core/parcel-bundler/src/utils/prettyError.js

wget -P ./node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/utils/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/b1e6d59cc44489f20013fa3171e09788978d7aed/packages/core/parcel-bundler/src/utils/emoji.js
```

Comment: Great detailed answer! Will try it out when I'm back at the dev machine next week.

Comment: Update: For anyone finding this, the referenced plugin does not work at all with Parcel v2. There is a [new Parcel v2 plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-transformer-transcrypt) for Transcrypt now that completely replaces the old one.